# Browser to phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

We've been working on browser to phone as per the doc provided by twilio which is in C# razor. We have to same the same for our clients using asp.net4.0.

When a phone number is entered in the textbox the call gets forwarded to the number that is specified in the VoiceURL of the TWIMLAPP rather than forwarding it to the number entered in the textbox.

Below listed are some of the queries that are haunting us;
How do we create dynamic TWIML's to pass the phone number to the Dial Verb? 
How to over write the VoiceURL of the TWIML app programmatically? 
Are there any examples in asp.net 4.0?

Comment: You have described an issue, but have not actually provided us with any information that we can use to help with it. Please post any relevant code, screenshots, or lists that we can use to help you work through the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Lets take your questions one at a time.

- How do we create dynamic TWIML's to pass the phone number to the Dial Verb?

TwiML is just XML, so there are a number of ways to dynamically generate XML in .NET.  We do provide a special library (available on NuGet) called [Twilio.TwiML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.TwiML/) that will generate the TwiML for you to return to Twilio.  I wrote a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-4-using-the-twilio-twiml-helper-library.html) a while ago that shows you how to use it.

If you want to generate a `<Dial>` verb using the TwiML library, you would do something like:

```
var response = new TwilioResponse();
response.Dial(phoneNumber);
string xml = response.ToString();
```

- How to over write the VoiceURL of the TWIML app programmatically?

The Twilio REST API can be used to modify a TwiML [Application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications).  The Twilio .NET helper library makes it easy to do this as well:

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient("[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]","[YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]");
client.UpdateApplication(applicationSid, friendlyName, applicationOptions);
```

Hope that helps.